# i'm getting alpha numeric imei in android google pixel phones

Tags: java, android, imei, google-pixel

when i'm trying to get IMEI from google pixel 3 (android 10), i'm getting alpha numeric data. if anyone knows the issue please let me know.

```
 public static String getUniqueIMEIId(Context context) {
    try {
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return "";
        }
        String imei = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
        Log.e("imei", "=" + imei);
        if (imei != null && !imei.isEmpty()) {
            return imei;
        } else {
            return android.os.Build.SERIAL;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "not_found";
}
```

Comment: How are you doing that?

Comment: adding permission in  manifest <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

Comment: adding permission won't return you the IMEI. show how you are getting the IMEI.

Comment: I added my method in post please check and i'm not getting imei in android 10 and other os works fine with this method - Thanks

Comment: in question you said that `i'm getting alpha numeric data`, and now you say that `i'm not getting imei`. So which one is right? Please decide.

Comment: Pardon, I mean to say the actual IMEI is 15 digit numeric in any device but i'm not getting that instead of that i'm getting 16 digit alpha numeric.

Comment: that is because of `else {
            return android.os.Build.SERIAL;
        }` which is alpha-numeric. `getDeviceId` is deprecated. Check the documentation for the information why and what to use instead of it. The documentation is the first place you should look at when something works not as you expect.